# TreeViewer custom node rendering (adding checkboxe and clickeable image)

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm actually trying to create a tree following that article : https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm

But the problem is that I need to add 2 clickable images (1 for reloading sub-nodes and 1 for adding new sub-node)

And as optional, if someone can explain me how to add a check box on sub-nodes so then I can delete from the parent node all selected sub-nodes

Thank you in advance for all your help

Comment: You would have to use `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` to draw the nodes yourself for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help greg, but do you have any example (or tutorial) that could help to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Buttons as you describe them, for adding items and reloading (sub-items), are typically placed outside a tree and act on the currently selected item. Is there a reason why you want them to be part of each item?